# Kafka Streams collecting stream items in lists

Tags: java, list, stream, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I want to partially collect items in lists in Kafka Streams after a given period of time or after 1000 items have been processed.

```
KStreamBuilder builder = new KStreamBuilder();
        KStream<String, String> kStream = builder.stream(topicTwo);
        KTable<String, String> kTable = builder.table(topicOne);

        kStream.join(kTable,
                (streamValue, tableValue) -> new CustomObject(streamValue, tableValue)
                .foreach((key, value) -> System.out.println(value));

        KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder, streamProperties);
        streams.start();

        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(streams::close));
```

This is my code. I don't know if I made myself clear enough, but what I want is a `List<CustomObject>` after every 1000 items processed or 5 seconds passed. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

For this I believe you need to define a custom [Transformer](https://kafka.apache.org/11/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/Transformer.html).

In its [transform](https://kafka.apache.org/11/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/Transformer.html#transform-K-V-) method, append messages to the list. If the list size reaches 1000 elements, create a new list and return the old one.

In its [init](https://kafka.apache.org/11/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/Transformer.html#init-org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.ProcessorContext-) method [schedule](https://kafka.apache.org/11/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/ProcessorContext.html#schedule-long-org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.PunctuationType-org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.Punctuator-) a punctuation function on the ProcessorContext, that emits the list of elements that are older than your time window.

Use [transform](https://kafka.apache.org/11/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStream.html#transform-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.TransformerSupplier-java.lang.String...-) method on the KStream after the join to add your custom transformer to your topology.

In your transformer it's probably best to keep the buffered elements in a [StateStore](https://kafka.apache.org/11/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/StateStore.html), rather than in an in-memory list to ensure no messages are lost on failover/rebalancing. StateStores are backed up in Kafka.